# Will my phone be unlocked after it factory resets itself?

Tags: factory-reset, motorola

I forgot the password of my phone, and it says after 4 more failed attempts that it will be wiped clean. If that happens, will my phone be unlocked and ready for use again? I really don't care about the data on it, because everything I had is easy to get back (mainly just social media apps like instagram/discord).

Any sort of help would be appreciated to the fullest, because I just want to be able to use my phone again.

Comment: that will trigger factory reset protection (FRP) which requires google account to unlock after factory reset. btw you will lose all pictures from /sdcard

Comment: Aha, so if I understand what you said correctly, I if I fill in my google password, I will be able to get back into my phone without any issues? @alecxs

Comment: right. if you are fine with factory reset, all you need is google password. you can remote factory reset from PC too, all you need is device connected to wifi https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager this way you are sure you know the password

Comment: So as long as I know my google password, I can get into my phone? @alecxs

Comment: yes (it is the google account used for google play)